# Events not being triggered in Application Module

Tags: events, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I cannot seem to get my events to fire off. This is my first time playing around with them. If you look, i create an event in the `init` method and then i try to fire it off in the `onBootstrap` method. The event should produce a die with the string, but its not. any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ControllerProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\InitProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ViewHelperProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

class Module implements 
    AutoloaderProviderInterface,
    ControllerProviderInterface,
    BootstrapListenerInterface,
    ServiceProviderInterface,
    ConfigProviderInterface,
    InitProviderInterface,
    ViewHelperProviderInterface
{
    public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $eventManager = $manager->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach('do',function($e){
            $event = $e->getName();
            $target = get_class($e->getTarget());
            $params = $e->getParams();
            $str = sprintf(
                'Handled event \"%s\" on target \"%s\", with parameters %s',
                $event,
                $target,
                json_encode($params)
            );
            die($str);
        });
    }

    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
    {
        $this->attachEventManagerToModuleRouteListener($e);        
        $this->setupDoctrineConnectionMappings($e);
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->trigger('do',$this,array('j','o','n'));
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return array_merge( 
            include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php',
            include __DIR__ . '/config/routes.config.php'            
        );
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/services.config.php';
    }

    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/controllers.config.php';
    }

    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/view.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__                    
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    private function attachEventManagerToModuleRouteListener(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }

    private function setupDoctrineConnectionMappings(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $driver = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('doctrine.connection.orm_default');
        $platform = $driver->getDatabasePlatform();
        $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
        $platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('set', 'string');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `EventManager` you're getting from the `ModuleManager` is a different `EventManager` than the `Application`'s `EventManager` which you let trigger the event `do`.

Since during Module initialization the Application is not yet available, you've to bind your listener to the event via the `SharedManager`.

So attaching to Application's event `do` would go like this

```
$sharedManager = $manager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
$sharedManager->attach(Application::class, 'do', function($e) {
    // event code
});
```

Please note that the shared manager requires the (an) identifier of the EventManager that's expected to trigger the event which in this case is (and often is) the classname of `Application`.